# Setting a timer for each table row JS

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I have a problem in setting a decreasing timer for the table rows in my code!

I've tried multiple solution but it's just not working

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var table = document.getElementById("bidsTable");
  var x = setInterval(function() { 
  for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    var endDate = row.cells[4];
      countDownDate = new Date(endDate.innerHTML.replace(/-/g, "/")).getTime();
    var countDown = row.cells[5];
    var now = new Date().getTime(); 
    var t = countDownDate - now; 
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
    var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60)); 
    var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)); 
    var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000); 
countDown.innerHTML = days + "d " 
+ hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "; 
    if (t < 0) { 
      clearInterval(x); 
    }
  }
}, 1000);} //1000 show the code every second
```

```html
<table  style="width: 100%" id="bidsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th >Amount</th>
      <th >Start Date</th>
      <th >Bids</th>
      <th >End Date</th>
      <th ></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td >Peugeot 406 car fro sale</td>
      <td >800000.00</td>
      <td >2020-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td >1</td>
      <td >2020-05-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >House for sale in Kubwa</td>
      <td >4000000.00</td>
      <td >2017-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td >0</td>
      <td >2017-06-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >Five hectare farming land for lease</td>
      <td >3000000.00</td>
      <td >2017-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td >0</td>
      <td >2017-07-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td id="demo" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

how can I make the counter decrease every second? 
    it only updates when I refresh the page

I guess it has to do with the loop or the setInterval method!

Comment: by removing  `clearInterval(x);`  your code just works

Comment: Because 2017 is less than today, and 2 of your  properties are for 2017.  Your clearing the interval if it finds any..

Answer (score 0):

in your code you defined `countDownDate` in a for loop for all three rows then you define `t = countDownDate - now` which makes t a negative number because when for loop ends and javascript starts to to run this part of the code the value of `countDownDate` represents time of  *Five hectare farming land for lease* which happened before now so `t = countDownDate - now` becomes a negative number then you check wether t is a negative number or not here

`if (t < 0) { 
      clearInterval(x); 
    }`

and because t is a negative number you just stop the interval and it only runs once

if you want to show 0 days 0 minutes  . . . for times that has passed i've modified your code as below :

```js
 window.onload = function() {



    var table = document.getElementById("bidsTable");

var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {

                                var endDate = row.cells[4];
                                countDownDate = new Date(endDate.innerHTML.replace(/-/g, "/")).getTime();
                                var countDown = row.cells[5];
                                var t = countDownDate - now;

var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((t%(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
if(t<0){
  days = 0;
  hours = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  seconds = 0;
}
countDown.innerHTML = days + "d "
+ hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
}
}, 1000);} //1000 show the code every second
```

```html
<table  style="width: 100%" id="bidsTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th >Amount</th>
      <th >Start Date</th>
      <th >Bids</th>
      <th >End Date</th>
      <th ></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td >Peugeot 406 car fro sale</td>
      <td >800000.00</td>
      <td >2020-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td >1</td>
      <td >2020-05-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >House for sale in Kubwa</td>
      <td >4000000.00</td>
      <td >2017-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td >0</td>
      <td >2017-06-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >Five hectare farming land for lease</td>
      <td >3000000.00</td>
      <td >2017-04-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td >0</td>
      <td >2017-07-10 3:48:47 PM</td>
      <td id="demo" ></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```